# picklist value should only be visible for admins only

Tags: validation

1. I have a field called type for opportunity object
2. for which I have created a picklist called" Access Agreement Renewal"
3. and then assigned a record type as " MXU oppoirtunities" to that picklist
4. Now i that picklist should be visible/ editable for admins only.

Could you please suggest me the best way to solve it

Note: I have tried it through validation rule

Comment: Create separate record type for the admin profile and assign the picklist value.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally show picklist values based upon Profile/Permissionset. Reading your question, it seems like that is what you want to do.

The only reasonable solution I can think of would be to implement a custom VisualForce page for this record type, and then manipulate the picklist using JavaScript. But that is a rabbit hole you should only go down if you *really* need this functionality.

Comment: Conditional picklists based on profile/permset are certainly possible via a record type: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_recordtypes_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_recordtypes_cheatsheet/recordtypes_cheatsheet.htm. In Winter 23 with dynamic forms and (screen) flow, this whole record type -> picklist dependency is [now also possible](https://unofficialsf.com/the-three-musketeers-arrive-in-winter-23-data-table-beta-in-operator-and-record-type-filtering-for-picklists/)

Comment: Fair comment.  Not really familiar with dynamic forms.